# MapReduce is working normally and suddenly restarts the process without aborting the Job (Sqoop)

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, sqoop

MapReduce is working normally and, suddenly, it restarts the process without aborting the Job (Sqoop), then at the end it duplicates the information in the table?

Comment: Sqoop is a retired Apache project. Is there a specific reason to continue using it?

Comment: legacy, the on premises environment will soon be turned off

Comment: Okay. From what I recall, Sqoop has an option for CRC checking, which may help with duplication. Otherwise, there are several places where "partial" or "duplicate" are mentioned in the docs. E.g. https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_controlling_the_import_process

Comment: Sqoop reads a .hql file, reading the execution log of the .hql file, MapReduce is started and at some point it restarts and with that the data is duplicated in the destination (table)
​

Comment: Okay. Did you use `--staging-table` as the docs show?

Comment: inside the .hql file there is a SQL statement to do an insert overwrite

Comment: Okay, that didn't answer my comment, and you've not shared your script in your question, so I'm not sure how we'd have known that

Comment: I don't understand about your question --staging-table

Comment: 1) You didn't say if you are running import or export. 2) The docs - "_Since Sqoop breaks down export process into multiple transactions, it is possible that a failed export job may result in partial data being committed to the database. This can further lead to subsequent jobs failing due to insert collisions in some cases, **or lead to duplicated data** in others. **You can overcome this problem by specifying a staging table via the `--staging-table` option**_" 3) You can also pass [`--validate`](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.7/SqoopUserGuide.html#_purpose_5)

Comment: There was a parameter inside the .hql file with the following instruction:
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.lockmgr.DummyTxnManager
I removed this parameter and the problem did not reoccur.